# How can I make an applet call and run another applet

Tags: java, applet

I have made a game as an applet however I want to add a "start" "close" menu at the beginning. I was wondering if its possible to make the menu as a separate applet and when "start" is pressed, it will call and run the other applet?

Comment: First of all, don't, this isn't really how you code should work. You start/close menus should be within the same applet context/container.  You could use something like `CardLayout` to vacillate the switching of the views between different panels, but from what you seem to be saying, you've coded all you logic directly into the applet itself, which is a bad idea, as you've discovered. Secondly, given the fact that most browsers are now days activly blocking applets, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to continue using them (and the added complexity in there management make them unappealing)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't, this isn't really how you code should work. Your start/close menus should be within the same applet context/container.

You could use something like `CardLayout` to vacillate the switching of the views between different panels.

[image: CardLayout]

This allows you to use the `Applet` simply as a container for other views and switch those views based on your own rules and requirements.  Take a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

But from what you seem to be saying, you've coded all you logic directly into the applet itself, which is a bad idea, as you've discovered.

Secondly, given the fact that most browsers are now days actively blocking applets, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to continue using them (and the added complexity in there management make them unappealing)

A better solution might to start by using a `JPanel` as you primary container, apply a `CardLayout` to it and having each view as separate components.  This now provides you the added flexibility of been able to decide how to display the program, applet, frame or other container